# Dictionaires (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have two dictionaries and I want to use  them to form a new dictionare where their names are the new keys. How can I do that?
This is what I am trying (and not succeding)

```
lft = {}
Selic_2021 = {}
Selic_2023 = {}


i= 1
while i < df.shape[0]:
    Selic_2021[df.iloc[i,0]] = df.iloc[i,1]
    Selic_2023[df1.iloc[i,0]] = df1.iloc[i,1]
    i = i+1


a = frozenset(Selic_2021.items())
b = frozenset(Selic_2023.items())
lft[a]
lft[b]
```

Comment: What i am lokking for is something like this:{"bitcoin": {"1357171200000": 0, "1357257600000": 0, "1357344000000": 0},"ethereum": {"1357171200000": 0, "1357257600000": 0, "1357344000000": 0}}

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
lft['Selic_2021'] = Selic_2021
lft['Selic_2022'] = Selic_2022
```